# Fetched Results Controller with NSPredicate vs. Core Data NSSet

Tags: iphone, core-data, nspredicate

Okay, so I have a UITableView hierarchy. The top level controller is for Categories, which are selected via Fetched Results Controller with no predicate for the Category Entity.

When a user taps a cell, they are advanced to the Items Table View Controller.

At this point, I assumed I should use another fetched results controller with an NSPredicate to filter out the results not matching the selecting category.

However, I've had a lot of difficulty building a predicate that does this. All the examples seem to be for search strings to attribute comparisons. Not comparing a CoreData Relationship.

So is it a better practice to use this method, or simply get the NSSet of items from the passed in Category Managed Object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second level view controller should have the selected Category set into it via dependency injection as a property.  Your second level view controller should only know that "it's" Category is X.  It does not need a NSFetchedResultsController at all because you already have all of the information you require via relationships on "it's" Category entity.

To do this, in your top level view controller when a Category is selected you get a pointer to it via the `NSFetchedResultsController`, instantiate the new view controller, set the Category property and then push the new view controller.

This will give you solid incapsulation and separation between your view controllers.